# CAS LDAP and database query

Tags: cas

I have a user authenticated against LDAP using CAS. I now have the UID. Is it possible to use CAS to also query an oracle database using the UID to get other user attributes stored from oracle?

I've tried to use SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao class in my bean but I can't get any attributes to release from it ... I'm not even sure if the query is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. authentication in CAS is different from attribute retrieval. You can authenticate via one source, and get attributes from another. Authentication is handled via authN handlers, and attribute retrieval is handled via attribute repositories.

Once you have retrieved attributes, you need to configure your service definition to release those attributes. You need to define an attribute policy that authorizes the release of all or select attributes.

See http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/integration/Attribute-Release.html

Comment: So does this involve custom code? I can't simply use SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao in the deployerConfigContext.xml. I have no problem releasing attributes from the LDAP query so I assume I would release them in the same way from my oracle query.

Comment: hi @Misagh. I have been working on cas-overlay for a week. I created cas-overlay via cas-initializer container with cassandra dependencies. I have cassandra db and I want to integrate cassandra and cas to auth process. In next time, I will probably integrate some LDAP to this configuration. Also, I should to use self-signed certificate to encrpyt traffic. Do you have any advice to me? Kind regards.